# Using jQuery in Cloud9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cloud9-ide

I am teaching myself how to program usign JS, jQuery, HTML and CSS.  I downloaded the jquery-master from github and use it in my project, however I still cannot get it to import into my HTML files so that I can utilize it.  Does anybody know how?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

you can use this js file you donot need to download js files you just need to place this script tag to each html page where you are trying to play with jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use this script and include your jquery code inside this script block

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('hi friend') </script>
```

hope this will works Thanks.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure to remove the "http" prefix from the src URL.